# Erlang serialization library

Tags: serialization, erlang, protocol-buffers

Does anybody know good and production ready serialization library for Erlang?

I have tried erlang_protobuffs - but it fails on its tests. I don't need to expose methods or anything like this, all I need is to encode/decode messages.

Is there anything else worth trying?

Comment: Piqi author here. I was going to post an answer but then noticed your comment. Piqi is stable and production-ready. Feel free to contact me if you have any questions about it.

Comment: Hi Anton! I just check piqi and saw that it requires OCalm to proceed. Seems too much for my task. I have about 12 messages that will be floating between several erlang systems, so at the moment I think custom old-style parsers will do the work.

Comment: Anton, is it possible to use piqi without OCalm somehow?

Comment: "I have about 12 messages that will be floating between several erlang systems" In this case, why not just use `term_to_binary`/`binary_to_term`?

Comment: Hi Alexey Romanov, my one week Erlang experience didn't tell me about `term_to_binary / binary_to_term`. Now I know! Thank you very much! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: MinimeDJ, if you need Erlang-to-Erlang communication, the simplest way is to handles this is to follow Alexey's advice and use `term_to_binary`/`binary_to_term`. Speaking of Piqi, if it is used for binary serialization, OCaml programs are used only for generating Erlang coders/decorders. See https://github.com/alavrik/piqi-erlang-examples for an example how to use Piqi.

Comment: Hi Anton, thank you very much for you reply on github! I will use pigi to exchange messages with other systems! Thank you again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Alexey Romanov said, try `term_to_binary` and `binary_to_term`. If you are talking between Erlang nodes, you don't even need this, because the Erlang runtime can do this for you transparently.

There are also libraries for (un)serializing these values in other languages. The keyword for this is BERT (binary erlang terms). The homepage contains some links to libraries: http://bert-rpc.org/