# Send tuple through tcp socket in Erlang

Tags: sockets, tcp, erlang

I'm trying to send a tuple using a tcp socket, I'm using gen_tcp:send(Socket, {elem1,elem2}) but I'm receiving this error, "bad value on output port 'tcp_inet' " can anyone tell me how can I send a tuple through a socket?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument must be a Packet:

```
Packet = string() | binary() | HttpPacket

HttpPacket = HttpRequest
           | HttpResponse
           | HttpHeader
           | http_eoh
           | HttpError
HttpRequest = {http_request, HttpMethod, HttpUri, HttpVersion}
HttpResponse =
    {http_response, HttpVersion, integer(), HttpString}
HttpHeader =
    {http_header,
     integer(),
     HttpField,
     Reserved :: term(),
     Value :: HttpString}
...
```

in your case  `{elem1,elem2}` does match any of these type and you get the error. The usual way to send an arbitrary term is to serialize it first:`term_to_binary(YourTerm)`

and deserialize it when you receive it : `binary_to_term(ReceivedBinary)`

Comment: My problem is that I'm sending that tuple to a Java client, do you know how do I deserialize it in Java?

Comment: Have a look at this http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817213/erlang-serialization-library and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775554/how-to-deserialize-an-string-serialized-erlang-term-into-a-jinterface-object-in

Comment: Or just do the serialisation and build the packet yourself in such a way the the Java client knows how to get each element and interpret it. This assumes that each element is something which has direct meaning to the Java client, for example not a tuple. :-)

Comment: a tuple of 2 atoms doesn't exist in java, so you need first to define how you will transform the erlang terms to get them understandable by the java program. JSON could be interesting for you, there are library to encode/decode both in Java and Erlang, you should check if the type interpretation match your needs.